# MySQL 5.6 parent / Child - Return newest (youngest child) record if given an Id

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.6

Given the following schema:

```
    |id|product_id|parent_id|ordered|sent|BO  |date_updated       |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    |1 |12313     |NULL     |2      |NULL|NULL|2019-03-01 13:24:00|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    |2 |12313     |1        |2      |1   |1   |2019-03-02 10:24:00|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    |3 |12313     |2        |2      |2   |0   |2019-03-04 16:40:00|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I am given a specific id (i.e. 2) How would I write the sql query to give me the newest record in the relationship (i.e. 3)?

Also, if I am given id 1 I need to return the latest (id 3) record as well. The relationship levels are not known.  It can have n number of children.

And if I am given id of 3 I need to return id 3(since it is the newest record).

Comment: "newest record in the relationship" - How do you define "relationship"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a query to run on MySQL 5.7 or earlier, I would use this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, MAX(date_updated) AS max_date_updated
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM yourTable
                        WHERE id = 1)  -- replace with your id value
    GROUP BY product_id
) t2
    ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id AND
       t1.date_updated = t2.max_date_updated;
```

As stated by @PaulSpiegel, we could also use a `LIMIT` subquery trick here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE product_id = (SELECT product_id FROM yourTable WHERE id = 1)
ORDER BY date_updated DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I got it somewhat working.  I was just wondering if product_id wasn't enough to query.  Meaning... what if there was an order no and products can be a part of many orders.  Also, I noticed you didn't use the parent_id at all.  Is there a similar way to go down the chain using the parent_ids?

Comment: @DrewBomb You are dropping on bomb on me at this point :-) ... you are now asking a completely different question.  If you need to do a hierarchical query, then ask a new question.

Comment: :)  Will do.  Thanks for getting me going in the right direction!  By the way... I love the reference!

Comment: Interesting solution. The same can be achieved with a simple `LIMIT 1` query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel In this case, that would work, but my first answer is a more general way to handle this.  Or, we could use `ROW_NUMBER` in MySQL 8+ or later.